# how to push from a checkout in github?

Tags: git, github

Upon coding, I realized I had made a mistake. I used

```
git checkout 7e57dbf5a7245...
```

to revert to an older commit. Now when I commit using

```
git commit -a
```

it says I am committing to a [detached HEAD f69ae14]. When I use

```
git push origin master
```

it says Everything's up to date... What do I type to push this [detached head] commit back to the master?

Comment: why do you add the rails(3) tag to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current log must be something like this

```
*-*-*-*[7e57db]-*-*-*<master>
       \
        *-*-*-*<HEAD>
```

Now you should reset `master` to current `HEAD` position, make `master` current branch and push it to `origin`:

```
git branch -f master HEAD
git checkout master
git push origin master
```

Note that you will lose all commits between `7e57db` and current `master`.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of what max said, your log initially looks like:

```
*-*[7e57db]-*-*<master>
```

You checkout 7e57db, and `git commit`, and you end up with:

```
*-*[7e57db]-*-*<master>
   \
    *<HEAD>
```

What you'd really like to do is take the commit at HEAD, and replay the changes it introduced on 7e57db onto master. The command you use for this is `git rebase`. Specifically, once you had made the commit, you would run:

```
git rebase master
```

At this point your history would be:

```
*-*[7e57db]-*-*<old-master>-*<master>
```

Then you could `git push origin master` to update the remote ref.

Answer (score 0):

you can reset the head to the detached head by using

```
git reset --hard 7e57dbf5a7245...
# and then 
git push origin master --force
```

by doing this, you will lose your changes between old and new head.

If you want to keep these changes, you could create a new branch from your detached head and merge it into your head, and then commit your changes and push the new branch.